# Ctrl + Page Up / Page Down not compatible with UserForm featuring refEdit

Tags: excel, vba

I created an "Index Match Wizard" using UserForm controls. The code works effectively, however, I am unable to use ctrl + pgup / pgdn while the userform is running. No other shortcuts appear to be unavailable. The requirement to use a mouse to click to a different tab largely eliminates the purpose of the macro.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ListBox1.AddItem "Exact"
ListBox1.AddItem "Approx."

End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MatchRangeOne = RefEdit1.Value
MatchRangeTwo = RefEdit2.Value
IndexRange = RefEdit3.Value

If ListBox1.Value = "Approx." Then

ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(" & RefEdit3.Value & ",MATCH(" & RefEdit1.Value & "," & RefEdit2.Value & ",1))"

Else

ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(" & RefEdit3.Value & ",MATCH(" & RefEdit1.Value & "," & RefEdit2.Value & ",0))"

End If

Unload IndexMatchWizardForm

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me? When the ref edit control is active, I am able to press Ctrl PG Up/Dwn to Navifate between sheets. Or Have I understood your query incorrectly? Maybe it is a nums lock issue?

Comment: Strange - when I try I cannot navigate between the sheets using Ctrl PG Up/Dwn. In fact, when I try to press Ctrl + Pg Dwn it is pasting the cell address in the ref edit control into the active cell. For example: "Sheet1!$K$15" gets pasted into that cell

Comment: Well I am able to navigate. Excel 2013 32 bit here